# Endpoints must be full URIs and include a scheme and host, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, bucket, laravel-7

I switched my storage from local to s3 (bucket aws) and fill in my .env file this variables:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="<my-key>"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="<my-secret>"
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="<a-region>"
AWS_BUCKET="<a-bucket>"
AWS_URL=
AWS_ENDPOINT=
```

Now, i call this function and it don't work, in local storage work:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->exists($this->file_name);
```

Any idea?

Comment: "It don't work" sounds a bit broad. What does that mean? Have you used the env variables anywhere in your service configuration?

Comment: No, only change this env variables in the .env file of the project, restart apache service an don't work but i resolved it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resolved, only comment this .env variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="<my-key>"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="<my-secret>"
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="<a-region>"
AWS_BUCKET="<a-bucket>"
#AWS_URL=
#AWS_ENDPOINT=
```